# Are cast-animations on stealthed allies visible to enemies?

Tags: league-of-legends

I recently played as Sona together with Twitch on bottom lane and that question came up:

If my Twitch ally is stealthed and I cast one of my abilities which affects him, can the enemy team see where the animation goes and do I give his position away to our enemies?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, enemy team in range see the graphical effect of Sona heal ability, even when it affects invisible allies.

Comment: May you have/know some videos or screenshots what it looks like? To see how I can recognize such things if I'm up against such combos

Comment: Is it also true for oriana's E ? I believed the ball would become invisible when attached to a stealthed ally, but I never really tested it.

Answer (score 1):

As Drake has said above, the graphical effect can still be seen by the opponent if Sona cast a heal on an invisible ally.

This is mainly because when Sona heals, her animation shows a green energy going towards the ally. However some champion's heals don't have targetable animation(such as Alistars heal) and will not reveal the location of an invisible ally.

Comment: Actually it might b a green colored energy not blue. i can't remember off the top of my head.

Comment: its green for heal, blue for AD/AP buff and pink for speed-buff ;)

Comment: It's green. Blue is the damaging aria.

Answer (score -2):

Every spell effect cast by VISIBLE allies will be VISIBLE, even if you are invisible (hiding in grass, etc).

Every targeted spell or attack you perform on enemies will make you VISIBLE to your enemies, even they cannot reach you or target you.

Comment: You don't answer the asked question

Comment: I think he did answer the question but just worded it not that well. I think he means that: "Every magic cast BY a visisble ally will be visible regardless of whether the recipient of the cast is visible or not.